# Can't get data after save to the redis in spring-data-redis 3.1.1

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis

Here's my simple code

```
@Service
classs MyService(
  private val redisTemplate: RedisTemplate<String, String>
) {
  fun why() {
        val res = redisTemplate.execute { c ->
            c.multi()
            val myKey = "member:holy".toByteArray()
            c.stringCommands().set(myKey, "test".toByteArray())
            val getResult = c.stringCommands().get(myKey)
            println("getResult $getResult")
            c.exec()
        }
        println(res)
    }
  }
```

getResult is `null`..!
I checked data is saved well.
The weird thing is `redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("member:holy")`  works well.
What's the problem?
And.. AFAIK,

```
redisTemplate.execute {
  c.multi()
  c.opsForValue()...
  ...
}
```

I saw this kind of example code in the docs. but there's no opsForValue method.
I'm using spring-data-redis 3.1.1